# Why do I get an error when my Caesar cipher program executes?

Tags: c

I am working on a Caesar cipher program. Currently i am trying to encrypt a message. I am writing a function to complete this task.
The compiler executes the code without any errors, but the final output of the code, which it is supposed to display the encrypted message, it produces, The encrypted message is:

```
����
```

Why might this be so??
My faulty code is below. Any form of help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
```

Comment: For what possible reason is *this* in the code: `return (encrypt_rot);` ? And that doesn't flag a big "conversion from `char (*)(char*,int)` to `char` " warning ? If it doesn't, *seriously* turn up your warning levels to pedantic levels and *fix* anything that is flagged. Do *not* throw in a bunch of casts to mask them; *fix* them.

Comment: I spot multiple misconceptions in your code, you need to read a book. e.g. char is not the same as a string, returning the function pointer is not the same as returning the results you have a local array a[] in encrypt_rot which does not exist outside that function  and so on.

Answer (score 3):

The code shouldn't even compile. (Type mismatch between `char(*)(char*, int)` and `char`.)

> ```
> return (encrypt_rot);
> ```

returns the address of the Function `encrypt_rot`. Maybe you wanted to write `return a;`. But then you should know, that you should not return the address of a local variable (`a` in this case) from a function because the variable is gone once the function returns to its caller and the returned pointer is no longer valid. Also the return type of `encrypt_rot` which is `char` doesn't match the type of `a` which is `char[100]` or, in this case with `return a;` it's `char *`.

I'd suggest you modify the parameter `x` in place:

```
void encrypt_rot(char x[100], int y)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 100 && x[i] != '\0'; ++i)
    {
        x[i] += y;
        if (x[i] > 'z')
            x[i] -= 26;
    }
}
```

Btw, you should think of better names for your variables.

> ```
> scanf(" %[^\n]s", message);
> ```

You should never, never, really never use the `%s` format specifier without specifying a SIZE to prevent buffer overflow:

```
scanf(" %99[^\n]", message);
```